# Best practices and/or advice for diamond relationing tables (Linq to SQL)

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have to import the content of 4 tables from an old database into SQL 2005 for easier reporting.

**Products** contains the id and product name, **ProductProperties** contains a variable number of properties for each product, **Ingredients** contains a variable number of ingredients for each product, and **IngredientProperties** contains the same properties as the product, specified for each ingredient.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/15068ece48.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/15068ece48.png)

With black I marked the relationships between the tables in the current design, and with red and green the possible foreign keys of **IngredientProperties** table.

Currently I am retrieving all the rows from **IngredientProperties**  for a given **IdProduct** and generate the report from that, but I would like to use the foreign keys for allowing future updates of the data.

What is the recommended design of the relationships of the **IngredientProperties** table for better usage with Linq?

Two sample reports:

```
// IdProduct = 1

        Price  Density
A1   25       10
A2   56       14

// IdProduct = 2

        Price  Density  Opacity
B1   87       21          60
B2   50       31          70
B3   12       10          90
```

Comment: Your relationship diagram isn't coming through... :(

Comment: The link doesnt work, it redirects me to some 110mb.com site that complains that there is no index.html setup so doesnt show the image file.

Comment: It works at home and at work :( I have updated the image link. Thank you for letting me know about it.

Comment: So IngredientProperties is intentionally denormalized? Do you want to think about normalizing everything to ensure data integrity?

Comment: The source database has no indexes or foreign keys. The arrows are based on matching data in the tables by visual comparison.

Comment: @Matt Sherman: the original tables are just like in the image. I would be glad to normalize the data, but I didn't encounter this kind of relation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your red arrows imply that a product could not have any rows in *IngredientProperties* unless the product had at least one matching row in *ProductProperties*.  Does it make sense that a product's ingredients can't have a density until the product has a density?  This restriction does not exist with only the "black arrow" FKs.

(Does it even make sense to repeat the properties for each product?  Does the density, opacity or price of ingredient A1 vary depending on which product it's incorporated into?)

The FK from *IngredientProperties* to *Ingredients* makes sense, but it should be a single aggregate key, not two separate FKs, which implies that the PK on *Ingredients* should also be an aggregate key, and the same applies to *ProductProperties*.

Edit:

Thanks for the update.  As I implied earlier, adding Foreign Keys to match the red/green arrows in your diagram will create constraints within the database that do not currently exist, which in turn could break existing code that uses the database if it, e.g., inserts into *ProductProperties* before inserting ingredients.

By using an aggregate key, you are basically saying that only one (*ProdID*, *IngredientID*) can exist in the Ingredients table.  It looks like that's already being done.  If the circled header items indicate indexes, then the data is already well-indexed.

I suspect that the "top" red arrow is incorrect, actually.  There are two *PropertyKey* rows, but I don't think they represent the same thing, since there's a separate *PropertyValue* in each table.  One pair represents properties of products, the other properties of ingredients, so linking them together will just cause confusion.

I'm still not 100% sure what you're looking for, but here are my recommendations:

1. Set up (or keep) PKs/indexes on each table as represented by the circled header items.
2. Set up FKs to match the black arrows from Ingredients and *PropductProperties*.
3. Set up FKs to match the green arrows.

The indexes are all that's needed for efficient join queries between tables.  The foreign keys serve to maintain "referential integrity."  For example, they prevent you from inserting properties for an ingredient that doesn't exist.

There are several things you could do to normalize this database as well, but I would not change it unless you have specific problems that need to be fixed.

Comment: There is no documentation on the database design and no vendor support. Also there are no relationships between the tables, at least not defined as foreign keys. All the arrows are based on matching data in the tables.

Comment: - The black arrows are the only one used at this time, and were defined by me.
- Each product can have different properties, and different ingredients. Each product property must be present also for each ingredient. And sadly the ingredient properties varies by time, so for two products the same ingredient can have different values for the same property, like density.

Comment: I could use an aggregate key (IdProduct + PropertyKey) between ProductProperties and IngredientProperties (red arrows), drop the IdProduct relation between Products and IngredientProperties (black arrow), and also use an aggregate key (IdProduct + IdIngredient) between IngredientProperties and Ingredients (green arrows), but I have a strange feeling about this.

Comment: The tables are exactly as presented in the image, but I'll be more than happy the change the design if it would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an Entity-Attribute-Value design in your `IngredientProperties` table. These kinds of designs can be downright dangerous if you're not ludicrously meticulous when creating your constraints. From what you've told about the problem at hand so far, you are free to change the schema, and you haven't specified a need to support arbitrary properties.

If the list of properties is, indeed, pre-defined and will rarely change, I would turn them into columns, for a schema that would look something like this, taking some liberties with style:

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
    ProductID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SerialNum varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Opacity int,
    Density int
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
    IngredientID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products (ProductID),
    SerialNum varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Price money NOT NULL,
    Opacity int,
    Density int
);
```

This does not, of course, answer your question directly. Instead, it makes the problem go away.  If the assumptions outlined above are correct, this should meet your needs, and be much more pleasant to work with.

Comment: The source tables are out of my hands, but I could define a different schema for the destination tables. I must check with the users if the list of properties can be frozen.